# Django 1.5: Cannot login on password change

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-authentication, django-users

I was trying to change a user's password in my django app using the following lines of code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
u = User.objects.get(email__exact='someemail@someting.com')
u.set_password('mynewpassword')
u.save()
```

(This user already exists in the User database)

There was no error or anything. But now I cannot login using the new password OR the old password !!

What happened ??

( This happens with all the users created. Unable to login to admin either ( even with changing using manage.py changepassword )

Comment: This code would not run like this. email and pwd are not defined. are you changing the passwords via shell? or via webform? maybe encoding is a problem?

Comment: My apologies, email and password are constants

Comment: @Jingo I don't think encoding is the problem. I ran these commands in shell first and they worked perfectly. I ran them again and BAM! Nothing works now. :/ Had to delete the db and start fresh. -_-

Comment: hmmm, sad, did you find the reason behind this?

Comment: @Jingo Nope. Was hoping someone here knew why this happened.

Comment: Can you show some sample password hashes stored in db. And also, the value of `PASSWORD_HASHERS` in settings.py, if any.